# How to change the terminal prompt to just current directory?

Tags: macos, path, terminal

I am using a Macbook Pro, and I wanted to change it to the current directory and a dollar sign prompt in Terminal. I've already looked at [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/how-to-hide-computer-name-and-user-name-in-terminal-command-prompt) [resources](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) to try and solve this issue.

I tried modifying the ~/.bashrc file and saving it but it did not seem to work.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PS1="\W$ ”
```

The last line is what I added to change the prompt.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should be done in .bash_profile, not .bashrc.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add a line containing this:

```
export PS1="\W\$ "
```

.bashrc is ONLY excuted when starting a sub-shell. bash login shell uses the following initialization scripts:

```
.bash_profile
.bash_login
.profile
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the dollar sign.  Like this:

```
$ PS1="\W\$ "
~$ cd tmp
/Users/philip/tmp
tmp$
```

And once you change your .bashrc you either need to logout/back-in or `. ~/.bashrc` to re source it.

I would humbly recommend not doing this.  Having a full path is very useful as 'tmp' directories could be anywhere.  Consider using "\w" which does relative path (ie. uses ~ to represent HOME)

Comment: I am considering using a full path. Regardless, I used `. ~/.bashrc` but when I have to use it every time I open a terminal window. Am I doing something wrong, or is there no workaround?