# Editing ~/.bash_profile doesn't customize command-line prompt properly

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line

Related Issue: [How to change the terminal prompt to just current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913134/how-to-change-the-terminal-prompt-to-just-current-directory)

I have added `export PS1="\w\$ "` to my `~/.bash_profile`, but the prompt for the command line just displays this:

```
\w$
```

It recognizes the backslash escape for the `$` character, but not for the filepath. It does the same thing when I use a capital 'W'.

Comment: I think you are actually running `zsh`, which may be started from `.bash_profile`, and `zsh` is interpreting the your prompt as the literal characters <backslash>, `w`, and `$`.

Comment: I think you have to log out of all sessions in order for `.bash_profile` to be applied. This include logging out of GUI.

Comment: @GRC, no, simply `source ~/.bash_profile` is sufficient (in each interactive shell)

Comment: I recommend the slightly more verbose procedure of putting `PS1="..."` (no `export`) in `.bashrc`, as the prompt is relevant for all interactive shells, not just login shells, then sourcing `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`. This is to accommodate the default behavior of macOS terminal emulators of starting login shells instead of regular interactive shells.

Comment: I think @chepner may be right.  Your PS1 declaration looks fine for bash, and it works for me.  You can check which shell you're in ultimately, by running `echo $0`

Comment: Another way to check if you are using `zsh` is to try `PS1="%~%# '` as your prompt, as that is (roughly) the `zsh` equivalent of the prompt you are trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my terminal is running zsh. I created `~/.zshrc` and wrote the following code:

```
PROMPT="%/\$ "
```

I referred to this resource to find the appropriate characters for displaying the current file path: [ZSH Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).